# How to remove an item in a list that equals a specific string

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list that contains this data: `"start it", "start it now", "don't start it"`.

I need to find and remove items that are **equal to** `"start it"`. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: list.RemoveAll(x => x.Equals("start it")); wiil do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `list.RemoveAll(x=>x=="start it");`
where `list` is your `List<string>`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to delete all items that contain that substring `"start it"` you have to do

```
List<string> items = new List<string>() { "start it", "start it now", "don't start it" };
items.RemoveAll(x => x.Contains("start it"));
```

if you want to remove all items that equal `"start it"` you have to

```
items.RemoveAll(x => x == "start it");
```

Comment: I tried doing that and it deletes all items containing "start it"

Comment: you wannt to delete only the item `"start it"` ?

Comment: Considering your question said to "remove the item**s**", then why shouldn't it remove all those items? Or when you said "contains **only**" you actually mean "equal to"? It is important to be specific when you write your question, and if possible you should write examples of input and output that you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

It removes all the string thatis **equal** to "start it".

```
list.RemoveAll(x => x.Equals("start it"));
```

It removes all the string that **contains** the sentence"start it".

```
list.RemoveAll(x => x.Contains("start it"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
List<string> items = new List<string>() { "start it now", "start it", "don't start it" };
items.RemoveAll(x => x.Equals("start it"));
//or
items.RemoveAll(x => x == "start it");
```

Both, `Contains` and `Equals` are using string comparison. Since your comparison is of type string, Contains will check if the passed parameter is part of the string, whereas Equals compares the complete string for equality.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 string   mystring = "start it,start it now,don't start it";
 ArrayList strings = new ArrayList(mystring.Split(new char[] { ',' }));

 for (int i = 0; i <strings.Count; i++)
 {
     if (strings[i].ToString()=="start it")
     {
         strings.RemoveAt(i);
     }
 }
```

and dont forget:
using System.Collections;

Answer (score -2):

Here is what you can do:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "start it", "start it now", "don't start it" };
list.RemoveAll(x => x.Contains("start it"));
```

Comment: @downvoters care to elaborate, so that I can fix my answer?